# Samba shares grant access to all users: permissions not working

Tags: server, permissions, samba, smb

I'm using Samba to create protected shares on Ubuntu Server that should be accessible by Windows computers. It does prompt me for a user name & password but one login grants access to all files, even those made for other users.
What am I doing wrong here?

So basically

```
su
cd
mkdir /files
mkdir /files/user1
mkdir /files/user2
mkdir /files/user3
chmod 777 /files/user1
chmod 777 /files/user2
chmod 777 /files/user3

vi /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

Under [global] I add:

```
security = user
wins support = yes
name resolve order = lmhosts host wins bcast
```

At the bottom:

```
[User1's files]
comment = User1's Files
path = /files/user1
browseable = yes
read only = no
valid user = user1

[User2's files]
comment = User2's Files
path = /files/user2
browseable = yes
read only = no
valid user = user2
```

And the same for user 3.

```
shutdown -r now
```

Now on the Windows PC logged in as user1 I try to access user2.
It prompts me for a username & password.
I enter the details for user1 and it grants me access, but it shouldn't do.
It then also grants me access to user3.
What am I doing wrong?

I tried adding

```
force user = user1
create mask = 0640
directory mask = 0750
```

but this didn't help.

The user accounts are on both Windows & the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the invalid user option on each share, or consider exporting their home folders.

Are you using a single Windows computer with multiple users?

- change world permissions - chmod 0770
- change the ownership of users sub-folder - chown user:*

useful links:

https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/samba-fileserver.html

Comment: I'll give it a try tomorrow. At the moment I'm using multiple windows computers each with one account but once I get this working I hope to add more users to each PC. When you say world permissions you mean chmod 0770 /files ie the main directory right? and chown on the subfolders?

Comment: yes like this chmod -R 0770 /files/user1 - this will change files which is owned by root to 0770 and user1!

Comment: If you have user1 on a windows client and user1 on your linux server. When you login windows that account will be used to authenticate and because the string and password matches it will authenticate with your linux server. When you then try to connect with user2 it will authenticate because you are passing it the right credentials. The best thing to do is configure permissions and ownership, also look at acls.